# Why does gdalwarp from ortho to longlat truncate the poles? It must be possible, otherwise Antarctica would not be there on the plate-carree

Tags: syntax, gis, gdal, map-projections, proj

[image: gdalwarp image truncated]

Why does gdalwarp from ortho to longlat truncate the poles? Lonlat should display -90 to +90 It is the same as eqc isn't it? They are synonyms for Plate-Carre or am I mistaken? Why is the gap showing up?
It must be possible otherwise Antarctica would not be there on the plate-carre.
Is there an interpolation argument I am missing?

Re-projecting an orthographic image to a equirectangular projection has some sort of problem.
The poles are getting truncated. is there a parameter I am missing?
Is there a difference between "eqc" "longlat" "plate-carree" ?
Is this a fundamental defect in gdal tools?

```
gdal_translate 
-of Gtiff 
-a_ullr -1666666 1666666 1666666 -1666666  
-a_srs 
    "+proj=ortho  
    +ellps=WGS84 
    +datum=WGS84 
    +lat_0=85 
    +lon_0=45"  
kat.png 
QQQQ-kat-ortho.tif 



gdalwarp 
-t_srs 
    "+proj=longlat 
    +datum=WGS84 
    +ellps=WGS84 
    +units=m"   
QQQQ-kat-ortho.tif
QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif 

gdal_merge.py  
-o QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.tif     
NE1_50M_SR_W_tenth.tif 
QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif

convert QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.tif QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.png

convert QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif QQQQ-kat-latlon.png
```

Comment: Can you show us the before and after images that show your issue clearly?

Comment: Thank you Ian. The cat is the before. The Plate-Carree and the Perspective is after. I used a 512x512px orthographic geotiff image of a cat in a circle to demonstrate the problem. As you may see, when the orthographic image of the cat is reprojected to longlat (or eqc), everything above 80 degrees is truncated. The cat is centered at 85N. If there is a built in limitation of 80 degrees for eqc gdalwarp, how are plate-Carree produced in gdal tools? -- Molly

Comment: Hallo again Ian, Perhaps you meant to see the actual geotiffs for insprection? I am not quite certain how to post an image in a comment. The output from gdalinfo has too many characters by far for a comment. What information from gdlinfo would be most useful? -- Molly

Comment: Yes, the actual tifs would be great.

Comment: I don't see a way to post them here in a comment. How do you want me to get them to you? I think most image hosting services corrupt the image tags or recompress lossless images.

Comment: ```
(source of BG map)
https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/packages/Natural_Earth_quick_start.zip

(512x512 image arbitrary  AAA-map-ortho.png)
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -1666666 1666666 1666666 -1666666 -a_srs "+proj=ortho +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=85 +lon_0=-30"  AAA-map-ortho.png AAA-map-ortho.tif

(truncated at 80N)
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m" AAA-map-ortho.tif AAA-map-longlat.tif

(more obvious here)
gdal_merge.py  -o AAA-full-M-longlat.tif     NE1_50M_SR_W_tenth.tif AAA-map-longlat.tif ```

Comment: https://postimg.cc/Whx0Mqng
https://postimg.cc/V5qyyXSL
https://postimg.cc/0zgc9BhT

Comment: `Best to reproduce the weird lacunae
Version -- GDAL 3.4.1
1)  CREATE SQUARE PNG 600x600 px WITH ALPHA CHANNEL CCCC
convert any.png -alpha on -scale 600x600 CCCC.png
2)  PNG TO ORTHO  DDDD
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -1666666 1666666 1666666 -1666666 -a_srs "+proj=ortho +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=85 +lon_0=-30"  CCCC.png DDDD.tif
3)  ORTHO TO LONGLAT EEEE  (Truncation occurs at 80-N)
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m" DDDD.tif EEEE.tif
4)  LONGLAT TO AEQD  FFFF
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=aeqd +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m" EEEE.tif FFFF.tif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reprojecting an orthographic (ortho) or perspective (nsper) image to  equirectangular (eqc) when the map includes polar latitudes,

REQUIRES the target extents argument: "-te -180 -90 +180 +90"

or some other set of -te corners that EXPLICITLY extends all the way up to +/-90 Latitudes, else the default xmax is set to Latitude 85. Perhaps gdal REALLY expects Mercator and snips off poles. ?? This does not appear in the documentation anywhere.

example:

`gdalwarp -te -180 -90 +180 +90 -t_srs "+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m" source_ORTHO.tif target_EQC.tif`